# GPS doesn't search on my Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm new on android programation and I have a problem with my aplication.
My Gps just doesn't search for location, or anything else.
And yes, my GPS is tunned on.
The manifest cointains the permitions:
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Could somebody help me?

```
public class LocationTest extends Activity implements
  LocationListener { 
private static final String[] A = { "invalid", "n/a", "fine", "coarse" };
private static final String[] P = { "invalid", "n/a", "low", "medium",
     "high" };
private static final String[] S = { "out of service",
     "temporarily unavailable", "available" };

private LocationManager mgr;
private TextView output;
private String best;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
  output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

  log("Location providers:");
  dumpProviders(); 

  Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
  best = mgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
  log("\nBest provider is: " + best);

  log("\nLocations (starting with last known):");
  if (best != null) {  
     Location location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(best);
     dumpLocation(location);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  // Start updates (doc recommends delay >= 60000 ms)
  if (best != null) {
     mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 15000, 1, this);
  }
  }

 @Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  // Stop updates to save power while app paused
  mgr.removeUpdates(this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  dumpLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  log("\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  log("\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
     Bundle extras) {
  log("\nProvider status changed: " + provider + ", status="
        + S[status] + ", extras=" + extras);
}

/** Write a string to the output window */
private void log(String string) {
  output.append(string + "\n");
}

/** Write information from all location providers */
private void dumpProviders() {
  List<String> providers = mgr.getAllProviders();
  for (String provider : providers) {
     dumpProvider(provider);
  }
}

/** Write information from a single location provider */
private void dumpProvider(String provider) {
  LocationProvider info = mgr.getProvider(provider);
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append("LocationProvider[")
        .append("name=")
        .append(info.getName())
        .append(",enabled=")
        .append(mgr.isProviderEnabled(provider))
        .append(",getAccuracy=")
        .append(A[info.getAccuracy() + 1])
        .append(",getPowerRequirement=")
        .append(P[info.getPowerRequirement() + 1])
        .append(",hasMonetaryCost=")
        .append(info.hasMonetaryCost())
        .append(",requiresCell=")
        .append(info.requiresCell())
        .append(",requiresNetwork=")
        .append(info.requiresNetwork())
        .append(",requiresSatellite=")
        .append(info.requiresSatellite())
        .append(",supportsAltitude=")
        .append(info.supportsAltitude())
        .append(",supportsBearing=")
        .append(info.supportsBearing())
        .append(",supportsSpeed=")
        .append(info.supportsSpeed())
        .append("]");
  log(builder.toString());
}

/** Describe the given location, which might be null */
private void dumpLocation(Location location) {
  if (location == null)
     log("\nLocation[unknown]");
  else
     log("\n" + location.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: What about the networks? Are they reporting your location? You must know that GPS sensors will not report locations it you're inside of a building. They only work outdoors.

Comment: .. and it'll take a hell lotta time if being run for the first time. Also please post the Logcat output.

Comment: Made an answer, I go home now, did far enough for today, will help tomorrow if you still need it (I can put this project for download tomorrow if you want).

Comment: In fact, this app works at version 2.3(Froyo), but doesn't works at my Jelly bean or any version higher than Froyo, and now? =/

Answer (score 0):

I normally don't do this, but I almost have to go.
This is the code I use, it works. (just put this in a new project).
I didn't clean it, because I ripped it from my other project, but it does work, when you make a new project and just copy/paste this.:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gps_loc = false;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String gps_location;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
        public void gotLocation(final Location location) {
            try {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();
                if (lat != 0.0 && lng != 0.0) {
                    String sLat;
                    String sLng;
                    sLat = Double.toString(lat);
                    sLng = Double.toString(lng);
                    gps_location = sLat + " " + sLng;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We got gps location!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("We got gps");
                    System.out.println("lat = "+lat);
                    System.out.println("lng = "+lng);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.

        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){

          return false;
        }
        if(gps_enabled){
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        }
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 35000);

        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
       @Override
        public void run() {

             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){

                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);

                 return;

             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }

    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }

}
```

Also add this in manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

No time to explain now, maybe tomorrow if you still need it.

It prints the latitude and longitude in your logcat.

Comment: In fact, this app works at version 2.3(Froyo), but doesn't works at my Jelly bean or any version higher than Froyo, and now? =/

Someone already had a problem like this?

Comment: @KleberRibeiro It works on mine (4.0.4), does it give any specific error?

I will test soon on my phone again. dropped my phone in bath when I felt in sleep :p. Need to fix that first.

Comment: there is no error, The GPS just doesn't search, do you know the icon that appear on the top of screen? So, it doesn't appears

Comment: @KleberRibeiro So also no message (on phone) "We got gps". Try to debug where to program stops, because it works for me. on 2.3.3 and 4.0.4

Comment: I think that you are not understanding. The program never stops, He just don't searchs for informations, and because of this, the icon, on the top of screen doesn't appear. In one phone it search, and in other, don't.

Comment: @KleberRibeiro The doesn't always appear indeed, but it does search on all my phones. I don't know what goes wrong, without an error or something it is hard to track what the problem is.